# Hide current flag from language selector

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, language

Our shop has two store views. One is Dutch the other is English. We use the following code to show the flags to choose a view.

```
<?php if (count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
    <div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>
                <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>"
                        alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
                </a>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Now we want to hide the flag for the current language. Because you don't need to see that. How can we create this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In css you could add `.lang-flag.selected {display: none;}`

Comment: yes, thats what we did.

Comment: So this is the answer to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something as easy as this?

```
<?php if (count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
    <div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
            <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
                <?php if($_lang->getId() != $this->getCurrentStoreId()): ?>
                    <a class="lang-flag" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
                    </a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have found a way:

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores()) > 1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
        <div class="langs-wrapper">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $selected = $_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId() ?>

<?php if(Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode() !=$_lang->getCode()):?>
        <a class="lang-flag<?php $selected && print ' selected' ?>" href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/flags/' . $_lang->getCode() . '.png');?>" class="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()) ?>">
        </a>
       <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```